# processing Xhtml files with Xdocument class adds unwanted elements

Tags: c#, xhtml, linq-to-xml

I am working on a project which requires me to process xhtml files to fix the content of certain  tags. The fixing itself is not a problem, however I have troubles when saving the files.

THe code I am using is:

```
 var spanNodesList = p.GetSpanNodesList(xDoc);

            foreach (XElement span in spanNodesList)
            {
                if (span.Value == null || span.Value == "")
                {
                    span.Remove();
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] words = p.SplitNodeText(span.Value);
                    XElement parent = span.Parent;
                    span.Remove();

                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                        parent.Add(new XElement("span", word,
                            new XAttribute("id", "w" + p.currentNodeID.ToString())));
                        p.currentNodeID++;
                    }                      
                }
            }

List<XElement> GetSpanNodesList(XDocument file)
    {
        //Get only 'word' nodes
        var spanNodes = file.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}span");
        if (spanNodes != null)
        {
            var spanNodesList = spanNodes.ToList();
            spanNodesList.RemoveAll(x => ((x.Attribute("id") == null) || !x.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("w")));
            return spanNodesList;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

As firstly, I couldn't get any  elements, I have found out somewhere in SO that I might need to add namespace reference to `file.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}span");` as it yielded no results. This has indeed helped and I get the nodes I want. However, the resulting code produces has two problems.

```
        <span id="w1" xmlns="">Word one</span>
        <span id="w2" xmlns="">Word two</span>
        <span id="w3" xmlns="">Word three</span>
```

It adds the xmlns attribute, which I don't need (and which was not in the original file) and it adds `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header. I assume this is expected behaviour resulting from what I coded, so my question is - what can I do to remove these 'problems'. Or perhaps there's a better way of dealing with xHtml files? Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but source files have references to a number of different namespaces...

Cheers
Bartosz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the `span` element, you're doing it without a namespace - whereas some ancestor element has set the default namespace. All you need to do is use the right namespace for your new elements:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
...
parent.Add(new XElement(ns + "span", ...);
```

Likewise you can use:

```
var spanNodes = file.Descendants(ns + "span");
```

which is rather more readable, IMO. You almost certainly don't need to worry about the XML declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon! Paradoxically, adding the namespace to each element removes the empty namespace attribute.
As for the XML Declaration, I agree it may not be an issue, but I need to return the files to the client the same way they came in.
(So XDocument is the right way to deal with xhtml?)
THanks again!

Comment: @Bartosz: It's not clear from the code you've given what you're doing with the document. You could always just use the root node instead.

Comment: I need to get text of some span elements and split it and put into separate span elements with proper IDs. This bit is simple.
I am not sure I understand what you mean by 'use the root node instead'

Comment: @Bartosz: Well if you need to avoid the XML declaration, don't save the `XDocument` - save its root element. So `doc.Root.Save(...)`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, doing `xDoc.Root.Save(path);` still puts the xml definition. Perhpaps it's in related to how my source looks like:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> [and so on up to the </html>]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61128/discussion-between-bartosz-and-jon-skeet).